# What's the difference between Collection and Fieldset in ZendFramework?

Tags: php, collections, zend-framework2, fieldset

can someone explain me the difference? 
Collection can be many fieldsets? And fieldsets is the "collection" of elements?

I'm right?

Comment: Brief questions like this are probably best hyperlinking to the relevant pages in the manual, so readers can be assured you've read the basic definitions. It also helps people to easily find those pages, so they can offer their own interpretations of the material within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML allows you to group related form fields with the help of the `<fieldset>` tag, as shown in the example below. The optional `<legend>` tag allows you to define the caption for the group.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose a payment method:</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal">PayPal</input>
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="card">Credit Card</input>
</fieldset>
```

In Zend Framework 2, the term "fieldset" means the same thing as in HTML - it allows you to define a group of form elements. Moreover, the entire form can be considered as a fieldset.

In Zend Framework 2, the term "collection" is analogous to fieldset,
because it allows you to group related form elements. But, it is designed for adding form elements dynamically by binding an array of objects to the form elements.